# Base64 decode json array sent from URL

Tags: c#, json

I want to decode a simple json array using C# that's stored in a GitHub repo to see if it contains a value.  I'm using the Newtonsoft json package.  I've read this thread: [Code for decoding/encoding a modified base64 URL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1228701/code-for-decoding-encoding-a-modified-base64-url), but I can't seem to implement the solution.  I get the following error:

> **System.FormatException**: The input is not a valid Base-64 string as it contains a non-base 64 character, more than two padding characters,
>   or an illegal character among the padding characters

, but I think there's also something going on with the code.

```
var value = "somestring";
var encodedTopicTypeURL ="https://api.github.com/repos/org/repo1/contents/sample.json";
string decodedTopicTypeURL;
byte[] buffer = Convert.FromBase64String(encodedTopicTypeURL);
decodedTopicTypeURL = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(buffer);

using (var webClient = new System.Net.WebClient())
{
    var topicTypeJson = webClient.DownloadString(decodedTopicTypeURL);
    JArray validTopicTypes = JArray.Parse(topicTypeJson);
    if (!validTopicTypes.Contains(value))
    {
        Logger.LogError($"Value not found");
     }
```

Json array:

```
[
"string1",
"string2",
"string3",
"string4",              
]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your question doesn't specify why you are trying to decode the URL from Base-64/ Actually encodedTopicTypeURL is just a normal string, why don't you use it directly as below?

```
var value = "somestring";
var url = "https://api.github.com/repos/org/repo1/contents/sample.json";

using (var webClient = new System.Net.WebClient())
{
    var topicTypeJson = webClient.DownloadString(url);
    JArray validTopicTypes = JArray.Parse(topicTypeJson);
    if (!validTopicTypes.Contains(value))
    {
        Logger.LogError($"Value not found");
     }
}
```

If you actually need to get the URL off of its base64 representation, then replace the following line

```
var encodedTopicTypeURL ="https://api.github.com/repos/org/repo1/contents/sample.json";
```

with this

```
var encodedTopicTypeURL ="aHR0cHM6Ly9hcGkuZ2l0aHViLmNvbS9yZXBvcy9vcmcvcmVwbzEvY29udGVudHMvc2FtcGxlLmpzb24=";
```

This way decodedTopicTypeURL will actually have the url value.

You can use [this](https://www.base64encode.org/) site to play around with Base64 encoding/decoding

Answer (score 1):

`https://api.github.com/repos/org/repo1/contents/sample.json` is not Base64 encoded string. It's Base64 representation is
`aHR0cHM6Ly9hcGkuZ2l0aHViLmNvbS9yZXBvcy9vcmcvcmVwbzEvY29udGVudHMvc2FtcGxlLmpzb24=`

You can download data and when you have it in string variable(I used `DownloadData(string url)` to retrieve it parse it to JObject, take it Values and look for content inside.

For example:

```
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        string url = @"https://api.github.com/";
        string searchString = "url";
        WebClient wc = new WebClient();
        wc.Headers.Add("user-agent", "Mozilla / 4.0(compatible; MSIE 6.0; Windows NT 5.2; .NET CLR 1.0.3705;)");
        try
        {
            byte[] dat = wc.DownloadData(url);
            string data = Encoding.ASCII.GetString(dat);
            var values = JObject.Parse(data).Values();
            bool stringFound = values.Any(x => x.Path.Contains(searchString) ||
                                               x.Value<string>().Contains(searchString)
                                         );
            if(stringFound)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("JSON contains search string");
            }
        }
        catch(Exception e)
        {
            throw;
        }

    }
```

I'm sure searching through values can be done better (;

Comment: Yes, I see the Base64 representation in the URL for json file in GitHub.  When you state it's not a string, what I would like to know is how to properly decode the JSON to access the keys to check for a value.  If you have a URL that shows how to do this or a code sample based on my question and code above.